# A problem about characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I would like you to help me with a problem. If we consider a matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
       4 & 2 &-1 & 6\\
       3 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
      -1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
       0 & 0 & 5 & 0
      \end{bmatrix}$$

the problem says that the characteristic polynomial is $P_A(\lambda) = (2-\lambda)(4-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(5-\lambda)$. However, when we calculate directly

$$P_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I),$$

where $I$ is the identity metrix, we arrive at

$$P_A(\lambda) = \lambda^4-7\lambda^3+5\lambda^2+52\lambda+40.$$

Hence, I have the following question. Is it possible to find another equivalent $A$ matrix using some property that preserves the characteristic polynomial and arrives at the proposed result? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For those wondering, the first $P_A(\lambda)$ expands to $\lambda^4-10\lambda^3+27\lambda^2-2\lambda-40$, while the second $P_A(\lambda)$ has two irrational roots and two complex roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just take the diagonal matrix
$$
B={\rm diag}(2,4,-1,5).
$$
It has the above characteristic polynomial
$$
P_B(t)=(t-2)(t-4)(t+1)(t-5).
$$

The matrix $A$ has indeed the characteristic polynomial you have computed, namely
$$
P_A(t)=t^4 - 7t^3 + 5t^2 + 52t + 40
$$
This polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. In particular it has no rational root.

Why should $A$ and $B$ be "equivalent"? The characteristic polynomials are definitely different, so the matrices cannot be equivalent, or similar.

Comment: That's just my question about this problem. When calculating the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$, we should find $P_A(\lambda) = \lambda^4-7\lambda^3+5\lambda^2+52\lambda+40$. I don't understand why the problem asks to prove that the characteristic polynomial is $P_A(\lambda) = (2-\lambda)(4-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)(5-\lambda)$...

Comment: Because there is a typo, I think. It was a different matrix, not at all related to this matrix. A typo usually doesn't give an "equivalent" matrix, but rather a completely new matrix with very different invariants. For example, the eigenvalues are completely different now.